# Use user email in Charge (SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi)

Tags: square-connect

i try add

```
'buyer_email_address'=>$post['email'],
```

and then make $transactions_api->charge

affter this i call $transactions_api->retrieveTransaction
and i dont see 'buyer_email_address'

also i try add

```
'billing_address'=>array(
    'address_line_1'=>$post['address'],
    'first_name'=>$post['first_name'],
    'last_name'=>$post['last_name']
),
```

and i dont see this values in transaction details

```
SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
(
    ...
    [tenders:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                (
                    ...
                    [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                    [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:protected] => 100
                            [currency:protected] => USD
                        )

                    [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                    [customer_id:protected] => 
                    [type:protected] => CARD
                    [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                        (
                            [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                            [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                (
                                    [id:protected] => 
                                    [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                    [last_4:protected] => 5858
                                    [exp_month:protected] => 
                                    [exp_year:protected] => 
                                    [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                    [billing_address:protected] => 
                                    [fingerprint:protected] => 
                                )

                            [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                        )

                    [cash_details:protected] => 
                )

        )

    [refunds:protected] => 
    [reference_id:protected] => 
    [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
    [client_id:protected] => 
    [order:protected] => 
    [shipping_address:protected] =>
```

How add information about client?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add customer information to a transaction, you should [Create a Customer](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createcustomer) and then pass the `customer_id` along to the Charge endpoint.

Comment: i see [here](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/ChargeRequest.md) field 'buyer_email_address'
i try use this - but when  i make request "retrieveTransaction" i dont see email.

it's field don't work and i must only create cutomer profile?

Comment: That field is intended for chargeback protection, not storing customer details.